# IE8 autostarts "phantom" flash video that can't be controlled

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, swfobject

I've got a project that has a flash-video that autostarts, with controls to pause/replay/mute/unmute.
It uses a cookie to keep track of user-changes so it won't autostart if the user turns it off.

BUT in Internet Explorer 8 it somehow automatically plays a version of the audio no matter what. I haven't been able to target the phantom video, but I have full control over the one I see; I can start, pause, rewind, mute, etc.

---

### What I'm trying to figure out is:

- how is IE8 automatically starting to play it?
- Is there a way to target the phantom audio and mute it?
- Is there a way to stop ALL computer audio, then start the video again?

If you have any different plans of attack I could use, or thoughts on this I'd really appreciate it.

The dev site is at ** removed **
This is only a bug in IE8 and below; I only care about fixing it in IE8.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed this by targeting IE8 and below and setting autostart to off.
I then found the places where the script creates functions to interact with the flash and adjusted them to target IE8 and start the movie if the cookie was set to autostart.

It's worked out great.

I can post more info about that if anyone needs examples.